# I keep getting the following error with cv2 when I use a specific upper and lower limit

Tags: python, opencv

So I have uploaded the code below. For example, if I set the `lower_limit = [0, 0, 0]` and `upper_limit = [50,255,255]`, I get no error whereas if I set the `lower_limit = [25, 0, 0]` and `upper_limit = [27.5,255,255]` (which is what I want), I keep getting the error—

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Keerthan S\OneDrive\Desktop\blood51\code.py", line 27, in 
    masking = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_pink, upper_pink)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1782: error: (-215:Assertion failed) lb.type() == ub.type() in function 'cv::inRange'
```

Code is below :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

saturation_pink = 0
saturation_blue = 0

brightness_pink = 0
brightness_blue = 0

img = cv2.imread("creat_tubes3.jpg")

height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

#img = img_cropless[200:900,200:900]


result = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,20,10,7,21)

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#cv2.imshow("HSV Image", hsv_img)

lower_pink = np.array([25, 0, 0])
upper_pink = np.array([27.5, 255, 255])

masking = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_pink, upper_pink)
#cv2.imshow("pink Color detection", masking)
result_pink = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=masking)
half_pink = cv2.resize(result_pink, (0, 0), fx = 0.1, fy = 0.1) #resizing the image
cv2.imshow("Reacted area - pink", half_pink)

for y in range(width):
   for x in range(height):
      saturation_pink = saturation_pink + result_pink[x][y][1] #*(100 - result1[y][x][0])
      brightness_pink = brightness_pink + result_pink[x][y][2]

print("pink saturation : ",saturation_pink)
#print("pink brightness : ",brightness_pink)


cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You cannot used float 27.5  You can do this 27. Add cv2.imshow("Image", img) before waitKey.

Comment: @KeerthanS You can use float value after converting the image to `float`